# how to debug with django?

Tags: django

I'm starting to learn django and I was wondering what's the best way to debug a django application?

More specifically, I'm looking for a way to print out variables, in an equivalent way to var_dump statements in php.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While running the development server, you can issue print statement that will get printed in the console output. You can also use pdb while handling a request and debug directly.

You could put these statements in your view code:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

to enter interactive debug and trace as long as you want or almost.

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) `runserver_plus`. It includes the super useful werkzeug debugger. Whenever an exception in dev-mode occurs you can view the code that caused the inspection and open a debug console in you browser that gives you full access to a python REPL with all variables at exception time.

Answer (score 1):

Put django in debug mode and you'll get stack traces when things fail.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a Django application now using Eclipse with the PyDev plugin.  It works really great as a traditional IDE, allowing me to set breakpoints, query the state, and such.

And Martin is right, runserver_plus is awesome.