# UnpicklingError invalid load key, '{'

Tags: python, mysql, pickle

I am working on an application which is in `Django`. I am trying to store some data structure `e.g. dictionary` in `MySQL` db. So i use Python `Pickle` module. It works fine when i store it in db using `pickle.dumps(some_structure)`. My DB field is `longblob` mode is `binary`.

But when i access the field of model object in django:

```
obj = someModel.get(pk=1)
some_structure = obj.field
content  = pickle.loads(some_structure)
```

it raises following error:

```
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '{'.
```

Please help me, i have tried google but it does'nt help me, also there is one similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915397/django-blob-model-field) but it is not related to my problem as i am storing in db.

Comment: I would suggest pickling your data to store it in the database is not the correct way to go about this. You should store your data in the database correctly, transforming your data into tables and fields.

Comment: The data is in `complex hierarchy (nested dictionaries)`. I can not save it in form of tables and fields. The data is result of some process which i later need to process in django on another `View`.

Comment: Then JSON is probably a better format than pickle. JSON is cross-platform, whereas pickle is implementation-specific.

Comment: Anyway pickled data is not possible to filter.

Comment: What model field type do you use?

Comment: @alex i am using `Text` field. I have also tried to create my own `Binary Model Field` storing in `base64` but also got the same error.

Comment: If base64 encoding doesn't help, then probably the problem is somewhere in your "pickling" code. '{' looks like str(dict()) not a pickle.dumps(dict()). Plz, inspect data stored in database and compare it with manually pickled object in python REPL. Once again, try debugger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638819/how-to-debug-with-django

Answer (score 23):

I encountered this error and I discovered that it was because I had tried to unpickle something that had not originally been pickled.

More specifically, I had stored a Python dict without pickling it, leading to the initial character `{`.

Thus, to solve the problem, you should try either:

- Not unpickling the string upon retrieval from the datastore, or
- Verifying that objects are being pickled prior to insertion into the datastore

Comment: Another way this can happen: trying to unpickle a **Git LFS** file without having done a proper LFS clone.

Answer (score 1):

A corrupt file may cause this issue. Replace the older pickle object with new one. It worked for me.